# How do I edit my .htaccess file to only redirect one domain on my server?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a server that has multiple domains hosted on it. I created an .htaccess file (for one of those domains) that redirects old pages to new ones on the same domain. The problem is that the redirects are automatically setup to redirect for all the domains pointing to the server. Is there a solution to this?

My current .htaccess file has this so far:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

(redirect area underneath)

The redirects work fine, but they apply to all the domains which I do not like

Comment: Then you probably put the `.htaccess` file in the wrong folder. Where did you put it? Remember `.htaccess`  only effects the folder where you put it, and subfolders

Comment: Like @RiggsFolly said, you've probably put it at your server's root. Put it in the public_html folder of the domain you want to redirect.